# Looking for a futuristic story about American football

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it was a collection of short stories. In a future where robots or simulations are replacing live sports events, two teams match up to play the last actual live game ever. 
Other than the time frame though, I think it was a fairly standard game. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Was it a collection of stories by the same author, or by different authors? Was it a sports-themed anthology, or was it robot-themed, or unthemed? **How long ago did you read it?**

Comment: I think I read a story like that in collection of short stories by rod serling but it's been so long ago I can't remember the name of the book. The players were robots and the game was televised. Does this help you at all?

Answer (score 11):

The short story you are describing sounds like "**The Last Superbowl**" by George R. R. Martin. (Yes, the creator of Game Of Thrones :-) ). I read it as part of an SF Sports novel which includes several other sports related stories; "[Run to Starlight, Sports Through Science Fiction](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12166846-run-to-starlight)"

A description of the story can be found below in which GRRM showcases a world in which computer simulations have replaced real football. Sort of a "fantasy league takes over the real league" situation.

You can find a pretty good description [here](http://agentpalmer.com/10635/media/the-written-word/the-last-superbowl-by-george-r-r-martin-is-a-science-fiction-epitaph-to-sports-as-we-know-it/):

> The last Superbowl – just think about it. No more National Football
>   League, no more National Basketball Association, no more Major League
>   Baseball, the players all replaced by pixels and simulations. The
>   piece is entitled “The Last Superbowl” because the NFL was the last
>   sport to fall to the computerized simulations. Martin explains that
>   the NBA and NHL disbanded in 2010, while the MLB lasted just until
>   2014, with the NFL holding on just long enough to have one last
>   Superbowl in 2016.

Comment: Nice find. You might want to consider re-adding your book recommendation as a comment :-)

Comment: @Richard.  Good suggestion.  For those seeking other SF Football stories, I might suggest Gary K. Wolf's "Killerbowl" from the same year (1975(.